# Readtimeout when using User Defined Function in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a single node Cassandra Cluster (Apache) with 2 vCPUs and around 16 GB RAM on AWS. We have around 28 GB of data uploaded into Cassandra.

Now Cassandra is working fine for select and group by queries using primary keys, however when using User Defined Functions to use aggregate functions on non-primary key - it is giving a timeout.

To elaborate - we have partition on Year, Month and Date for a 3 year data. Now for example if two columns are - Bill_ID and Bill_Amount we want to have a sum of Bill_Amount by Bill_ID using UDF.

Kind of confused here as I believe that if the info says it has received 1 response, why should it give a message of timeout if it has received it? Why are we getting a timeout and that too only when using User Defined functions?

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 1 responses." info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

We have increase read timeouts in the yaml file to as high as 10 minutes.

Edit - Adding the screenshot of the query. The results displayed before setting --request-timeout and post that using UDF. The table has 150 million rows with over 1095 partitions only for 3 years of data - with primary keys been year, day and month.

[image: Screenshot of the query used]

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the timeouts also on client side, cqlsh for example:

**cqlsh --request-timeout=3600**

Comment: Tried that .. in fact made it 36,000 - but yet no results. Have updated the question with the screenshot.

Comment: Can you try to tun repair on both nodes?

Comment: It is a single node Cassandra Cluster.

Comment: I use : cqlsh --connect-timeout=3600 --request-timeout=3600, but still show error. I can't drop the table too